# javascript - AngularJS + ng file upload + Sails JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js, ng-file-upload

I need to send so information together with each file I upload. The documentation says that I can achieve that with the data parameter but I cant access it from my action in my Sails controller.

Frontend:

```
Upload.upload({ url: '/file/upload', arrayKey: '', data: { file: $scope.files, otherInfo: {user: user, person: 12 }}}).....
```

Sails JS:

```
req.file('file').upload({ dirname: '../../websrc/uploads' }, function(err, files) {
      if (err) return res.serverError(err);
      return res.json({
        message: files.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!',
        files: files
      });
    });
```

If I log files, I see X objects like this:

```
UploadedFileMetadata[0]
extra: undefined
fd: "/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/uploads/24fd1f66-36df-40ec-bed3-45e18df77469.jpg"
field: "file"
filename: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg"
size: 199247
status: "bufferingOrWriting"
stream: PassThrough
type: "image/jpeg"
```

How can I send information for each one of my files and access it from my server?

Comment: If you see the network tab of your browser and look for that post request you will see that those information are being sent to the server. So you gotta figure out how to read it on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $scope.uploadFiles = function () {

            var request = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/fileupload/',
                data: formdata,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined
                }
            };

            // SEND THE FILES.
            $http(request)
                .success(function (d) {
                    alert(d);
                })
                .error(function () {
                });
```